# Envio valor select

Tags: laravel-5

Hay alguna manera de poder seleccionar el valor de un select y poderlo enviar en el  formulario?

```
<td>
    <select name="confirmar" id="confirmar" class=" form-control" required>
        <option value="valor1">Pendiente</option>
        <option value="valor2">revisado</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <form action="{{action('CuentaController@destroy', $usuario->id)}}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Como lo tengo aqui no sabria como incluir ese valor en el formulario.

Comment: tienes incluido JQuery en tu proyecto?

Comment: nop... esta con php por ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todos los valores que quieras enviar con el formulario tienen que estar definidos dentro del mismo:

```
<form action="{{action('CuentaController@destroy', $usuario->id)}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="confirmar" id="confirmar" class=" form-control" required>
                    <option value="valor1">Pendiente</option>
                    <option value="valor2">revisado</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```